Why do the bases in DNA not repel each other?
The bases in DNA are, well, basic. Adenine has a first pK$_b$ of 4.20 (Wikipedia), guanine 1.7 (Wikipedia), cytosine 1.8 (Wikipedia) and thymine 4.3 (Wikipedia). Under physiological pH of 7.4, all of these would be protonated, meaning each base in DNA would exhibit at least a 1+ charge. That would mean they would repel one another. As a vague order-of-magnitude approximation, I estimated the electrostatic potential energy in two elementary charges ($1.6*10^{-19} $ C) at a distance of 1 nm, which yielded an electrical potential energy of $2.3*10^{-19} $ J. (calculator) Converted to kJ/mol, this is ~136 kJ/mol. The hydrogen bonds in cells are only 6-30 kJ/mol strong, (source) so even a triple hydrogen bond remains below this value. So, I would expect interactions between nitrogenous bases to be energetically unfavorable.
Why is this not the case?

You got wrong values. For ex. adenine's 4.15 is acidity of conjugate acid, not pKb. They are weak bases and DNA binds to much more strongly basic histones. In result the bases are hardly protonated at all.

pKa is the pH at which a molecule occurs 50 % protonated and 50 % deprotonated. Protonated does not always mean positive charge as we can also look at the pair between deprotonated negatively charged molecule that gets neutral upon protonation. And it gets confusing when there are multiple protonation sites in a single molecule like in DNA bases.
Be aware that we always look at the equilibrium between two species when thinking about pKa. In this case we have 3 species in the equilibrium.
deprotonated<-neutral->protonated, i.e. two pKa values for the same molecule.
The distribution at physiological pH can be calculated over Henderson Hasselbalch equation
pH=pKa+log(base/acid)
10^(7.4-pKa)=Base/Acid
Guanines pKa is 9.65 for the N1 deprotonated (minus charge)/neutral pair and 3.20 for the N7 protonated (positive charge)/neutral pair
GHH+ <-3.2- GH -9.65-> G-
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp020774x
so at pH 7.4 only 0.6 % occur in the deprotonated negatively charged state. For the protonated positively charged state it is 0.006 %. The predominant form is the neutral molecule.
For exact concentration of all three I lack motivation.
Thymine pKa 9.5 for the N1 deprotonated/neutral pair
Here about the same
Adenine pKa 4.2 for protonated/neutral and 9.8 for deprotonated/neutral form
https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2003/cp/b212779m/unauth
So the "Bases" are predominantly in their neutral uncharged state and I think their name results from some historical incorrect attributions

Thanks. Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29925/why-does-high-ph-result-in-the-denaturation-of-dna

I would suggest reading more on the topic, considering for example also entropic contributions to the double helix.
Here is a recent review including a large amount of historical background.
Here is an experimental study characterizing charge repulsion of the helices.
We can look in these papers and find that cations in solution are crucial for ameliorating charge repulsion, (not between the nucleobases, which as rightly pointed out in the accepted answer are neutral under physiological conditions) but between the negatively charged backbones:

Cations are able to interact with negatively charged DNA via non-specific electrostatic coupling and hence universally screen the like-charge repulsion between DNA... Since continuum theories always predict DNA–DNA repulsion, the multivalent cation induced attraction (MCIA), driven by electrostatics, necessarily arises from spatial correlations between DNA charges and ions.

